# Install Facebooker on Rails 3RC With Ruby 1.9.2-RC2

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebooker

I am trying to install the **Facebooker** plugin on **Rails 3 RC** with **Ruby 1.9.2-RC2** but I am having some problems.

when I run

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/joren/facebooker.git
```

I get the following error

```
Plugin not found: ["git://github.com/joren/facebooker.git"]
```

and the facebooker.yml configuration file is not being generated.

Any suggestions on how I could get the **Facebooker** plugin to install or detailed instructions on another way to use  **Facebooker** with **Rails 3** would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I was able to get the plugin installed but I cannot use any of the rake commands.  If I run " rake facebooker:setup " or " rake  facebooker:tunnel:start ", I get an error saying "can't convert nil to string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised if this would work at all. I don't plan on supporting Facebooker on Rails 3. I would use Facebooker2 instead. It needs a patch for the JS helpers, but that's about it.